# add double xticks on seaborn including normalized count

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

I am plotting some countplots using seaborn

```
ax = sns.countplot(y='mydata', data=df,order = myorder).
```

[image]

Now I would like to show on my xlabel at the same time the count (as shown now), and simultaneously the fraction of the total for the same bar as % (count/sum all counts)
Can this be achieved easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FuncFormatter` to create custom labels. In this case you would divide the counts by the total and put them after a linebreak.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

p = np.random.randint(2,26,10)
s = pd.Series(np.random.choice(np.arange(40,50), size=400, p=p/p.sum()))

counts = s.value_counts(sort=False)
total = counts.sum()

ax = counts.plot.barh()
ax.set_xlabel("counts")

fmt = lambda x, pos: f"{x:g}\n{x/total*100:g}%"
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(fmt))
ax.figure.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]